# public static function php pass variable

Tags: php, function, static

I need to pass a variable from a static function to another within the same class.
I do not write the full code, I need the theoretical procedure

```
enter code here

class One
{

public static function One()
{
/**
*  some code extract from DB $one
*/
}

public static function two()
{
/**
*  I need to retrieve the variable $one to use it in another query DB
*/
}

}
```

Note:

you can't use $this in a static function

Comment: You can define $one as a static variable in the class, then you will be able to access it in function two

Answer (score 2):

Declare $one as a static variable:

```
private static $one;
```

And you can access it using : `self::$one`

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your variable within your One class, then you can retrieve it using `self` and the scope resolution operator `::`.

```
class One {
 private static $one;
 public static function One() {
  self::$one = something_from_your_db();
 }

 public static function two() {
  do_something(self::$one);
 }
}
```

Comment: the variable within `one()` method should be `self::$one = `

Comment: Thanks Rahil for the double check, fixed!